# Como puedo evitar que mis documentos .pdf sean indexados por motores de busqueda?

Tags: web, .htaccess, hosting, seo

Tengo una web donde tu puedes subir archivos .pdf, en ella el archivo queda persistido en el hosting, y puedes acceder al mismo cuando colocas la url para poder verlo o descargarlo.

Hace poco note que cuando ingreso la url base de la web, adicional vi que esta listando todos los archivos .pdf que estan persistidos. Y no debe ser asi. He estado buscando configuraciones con el HTACCESS pero nada me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo creando un archivo llamado **robots.txt** en la raiz de tu web

## desabilitar carpeta pdfs:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: AdsBot-Google
Disallow: /pdfs/
```

## desabilitar por tipo de archivo:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*.pdf$
```

## desabilitar archivo o url especifica para cualquier bot:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /home.html
```

## referencia:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/create-robots-txt

Comment: Perfecto, ya la puse en practica, voy a esperar unos dias a ver si ya no aparecen listadas.